# How close does my testing accuracy need to be to my training accuracy for ML model

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I've built a Random Forrest ML model. My train accuracy is around 97% and my test accuracy is around 85%.

Is this normal or is this too big of a difference? I know there is probably overfitting, but if the test accuracy is high at 85%, does it matter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

check performance by using cross validation.  cross validation helps you see how your model will perform with new data.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111968/random-forest-how-to-handle-overfitting

check your model for overfitting using mean squared error (regressor)

https://mljar.com/blog/random-forest-overfitting/

check for model overfitting with a (classifier)

[How do I solve overfitting in random forest of Python sklearn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463281/how-do-i-solve-overfitting-in-random-forest-of-python-sklearn)